# Add Percentile_Inc to Excel 2011 MAC?

Tags: excel, excel-2011

It semmes that Mac 2011 does not includes Percentile_Inc.

My question is simple, is it possible to add Percentile_Inc in Excel 2011 MAC version ?

Thanks in advance.

bee

Comment: `application.Percentile_Inc()` seems ok in Excel 2010, are you sure it's not in 2011 Mac version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean `PERCENTILE.INC` function which works on Excel 2011 as well. Please see this article

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/mac-excel-help/percentile-inc-function-HA102927917.aspx

Quote from that link

```
Applies to:
Excel for Mac 2011

PERCENTILE.INC function

Returns the k-th percentile of values in a range, where k is in the range 0 to 1, 
inclusive. You can use this function to establish a threshold of acceptance. 
For example, you can decide to examine candidates who score above the ninetieth 
percentile.

Syntax

PERCENTILE.INC(array,k)
```

**Followup from Comments**

If you are doing it from VBA then you need to use

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(Range("A1:A" & i),0.9)
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replays.  With this code :  min_seuil = Percentile.INC(Range("A1:A" & i), 0.9), I have this error : object required...  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are doing this in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `PERCENTILE.INC`? According to [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/mac-excel-help/list-of-all-functions-by-category-HA102927825.aspx) it should be included (under statistical functions)...... but you can also use simple `PERCENTILE` function, it does exactly the same.

Comment: + 1 I has posted it as a comment and then deleted it to post it as an answer and in meanwhile you posted it :p